# How to convert Html to a formatted string

Tags: java

The SpringBoot framework is used. I now get a string with an html tag, such as `"<p>Hello</p><p>Good afternoon</p>"`. I want to parse it into a formatted String on the back end and export it to an Excel spreadsheet to preserve the format.

Such as:

```
Hello
Good afternoon
```

How to solve it.

I am now using EasyExcel export, but the premise is to have this String with format, how to solve

Comment: Rendering HTML is incredibly complicated: There are pretty much 2 major browser engines out there, period. Should it support all HTML? Should it support CSS? Javascript? Or just very very basic HTML?

Comment: Only simple html is included, and the rich text generated by the front end is a piece of html that exists in the database. Now I want to convert this to a formatted string on the back end in order to retain the format when exporting to Excel cells.